# Unable to see full content of md-card in angular 2 and angular material

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I am trying to md-card in a list but when I display the content of card, it is only showing the title and sub-title. My html code looks like

```
<md-nav-list>
  <md-list-item *ngFor="let contact of contacts" fxLayout="column">
    <md-card class="card-class">
      <md-card-header>
        <div md-card-avatar class="sample-image"></div>
        <md-card-title>{{contact.name}}</md-card-title>
        <md-card-subtitle>{{contact.email}}</md-card-subtitle>
      </md-card-header>
      <img md-card-image="../assets/image.jpg">
      <md-card-content>
        <p>Address: {{contact.address}}</p>
        <p>Phone Number: {{contact.phoneNumber}}</p>
      </md-card-content>
      <md-card-actions>
        <button md-button>EDIT</button>
      </md-card-actions>
    </md-card>
  </md-list-item>
</md-nav-list>
```

associated css is

```
.card-class{
  width: 600px;
}

.sample-image{
  background-image: url('../../assets/image.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
}
```

When I am trying to load it is cutting the content of card, I wants card to take full width and display everything.

[image]

at the end of list it is showing everything.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried putting `display: flex` on your header and content elements parent? If this doesn't work try to downgrade to older material `    "@angular/material": "2.0.0-beta.1"`, based on my experience the latest material library is kinda messed up.

Comment: Just my 2 cents, why do you need to put the cards in an md-nav-list? Why not have just a parent div with `fxLayout="column"` and inside the `md-card` with the `*ngFor` on it ?

Comment: @AndreiMatracaru Thank you. I am new to material so I did not know.

Answer (score 0):

it is a css problem you need to override the class mat-list-item-content and modify height to the size you need.

```
.mat-list-item-content{
    height:180px;
 }
```